# Laravel 5.4 Register notfoundhttpexception

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I created a new laravel 5.4 Project + auth.

These are the steps I did.

1. laravel new app
2. laravel make:auth
3. php artisan migrate

Now if I try to Register I get following error:

```
notfoundhttpexception in routecollection.php line 161
```

The Redirect in my RegisterController Looks like this:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

and the home.blade.php file exists under ressources/views.

If I try to Change the URL to my main page I get this error:

```
View [login] not found
```

The user is still created. if I delete the user the error view[Login] dissappears.

My routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); // @index Returns to 'login'
```

But I still get the error any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a route for `/home`:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: @Micheasl you still need to add a route for `/home`. Update `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` to what Alexey suggests.

Comment: ok I did that but I still get this error `View [login] not found.`

Comment: @Micheasl this is not related to your original question. You're getting the second error because you're using `route('login')` instead of `url('login')` somewhere in your app.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it is strange because I only did those steps above,

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` 
@Alexey Mezenin [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43065721/7399894), you must either fix route in `routes`, or change `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in your `RegisterController` and `LoginController`

Concerning `View [login] not found` 
`RegisterController` is doing its job, validating data and saving user to db, but it looks like you are returning login view in your `HomeController`, and probably the path is wrong, as it should be `auth/login`.
Or you can instead of `return view('auth/login')` try `return redirect('login')`, if that is what youre aiming for.